# Scheme - eq? compare between 2 strings?

Tags: scheme

I have a problem in my program.

I have a condition that compare between 2 string:

> (if (eq? (exp1) (exp2)))

When exp1 give me a string, and exp2 give me a string. To be sure, when I change the "eq?" to "=", it give me the next problem:

> =: expects type <number> as 2nd
>   argument, given: ie; other arguments
>   were: ie.

When I'm running the program, the function **doesnt** enter to the first expression in the "if" function, and enter to the second one (meaning the condition is false).

What can I do?

Thank you.

Comment: my interpreter has `string=?`

Comment: when I change it to "string=?", it give me the next problem: string=?: expects type <string> as 1st argument, given: ie; other arguments were: ie. but "ie" is a string, No?

Comment: just clarify - "ie" is one of the values in a long list, and I got it after I did (car list)

Comment: I think you're going to have to paste some more code for us to be able to debug this any further.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the problem. I can't delete the question.

Comment: Advice, possibly unwelcome :): In order to get good help, you need to distill your misunderstanding into a very small program that doesn't behave as you expect. In fact, doing this will *often* allow you to discover the source of your misunderstanding yourself. In this case, for instance, try replacing <code>(exp1)</code> with the actual value that is the result of exp1. See if that helps you understand what's going on. If not, then post away, and you'll probably get more helpful responses.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Equivalence predicates](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.5) section of R6RS, you should be using `equal?`, not `eq?`, which instead tests whether its two arguments are exactly the same object (not two objects with the same value).

```
(eq? "a" "a")                           ; unspecified
(equal? "abc" "abc")                    ; #t
```

As knivil notes in a comment, the [Strings](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-2.html#node_toc_node_sec_11.12) section also mentions `string=?`, specifically for string comparisons, which probably avoids doing a type check.

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it. the same problem. it enter to the second exp (meaning equal? ie ie =>false)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a little helper function for this problem.

```
; test if eq?
(define ==
  (lambda (x y)
    (if (and (string? x) (string? y))
      (string=? x y)
      (if (or (string? x) (string? y))
            (= 1 0) ;return false
            (equal? x y)))))
(define a "aString")
(define l '("aString" "aOtherString"))
(== (car l) a) ; true
(== 1 1) ; true
(== 1 0) ; false
(== "a" 1) ; false diff. type
(== "a" "b") ; false
(== "a" "a") ; true
(== '("a" "b") '("a" "b"))
```

Comment: how is this different from `equal?`

Comment: What @newacct said -- this is a (very obscure) implementation that works the same as `equal?`.  BTW, you can use `#f` or `#false` (and usually also `false`) directly, instead of that `(= 1 0)`.